# Find the diameter of a binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to find the diameter of a binary tree (Path length between any two nodes in the tree containing maximum number of nodes.) in java.

my code snippet:

```
public int diametre(Node node, int d)
{
    if(node==null)
        return 0;

    lh=diametre(node.left, d);
    rh=diametre(node.right, d);

    if(lh+rh+1>d)
        d=lh+rh+1;

    return findMax(lh, rh)+1;
}
```

In main method:

```
 System.out.println( bst.diametre(root,0) );
```

Logic:
Its actually post-order logic. variable 'd' refers to the diameter of the sub-tree (In that iteration.). It will be updated as and when some larger value found.
'lh' refers to : Left sub tree's height.
'rh' refers to : right sub tree's height.

But its giving wrong output.

Tree considered:

```
   5
  / \
 /   \
1     8
 \    /\
  \  /  \
  3  6   9
```

Idle output: 5

But this code is giving 3.

Can some one figure out where the problem is...

Comment: You should do some debugging to find where your code's behaviour success from what you expect.

Comment: First, think of the algorithm. In your code, it's not clear what d stands for. Note that the assignment to it has no effect since it isn't used later.

Comment: Its actually post-order logic. and d refers to the diameter of the sub-tree (In that iteration.). It will be updated as and when some larger value found.

Comment: @loknath: But the update won't be noticed anywhere. Java passes parameters by value, always.

Comment: if u use an class instance variable, it should be fine. also you should print out d instead the return value

Answer (score 10):

```
public int diameter (Node root)
{
    if (root == null) return 0;
    else return Math.max (
        diameter (root.left), 
        Math.max (
            diameter (root.right),
            height (root.left) + height (root.right) + 1));
}

public int height (Node root)
{
    if (root == null) return 0;
    else return 1 + Math.max (height (root.left), height (root.right));
}
```

Comment: The last line should say root.left instead of root.length.

Comment: I think the runtime of this is O(n*log(n)), since you need to go through each node, recursively for diameter and for each find the height (log(n)). You should retrieve the height while you are in the node and computing the diameter

Answer (score 1):

You find a diameter of a tree by running a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from any node and then another BFS from the furthest node(the node last visited during the first BFS). The diameter is formed by the node last visited in the first BFS and the node last visited in the first BFS. The fact that the tree is binary does not affect the algorithm.

EDIT: changing the value of `d` in the code you have written will not affect the argument you pass as primitive types are not passed by reference in java.

Comment: I see your point. If this code is in C++ it would have been worked right.(if we pass variable d by reference).

Comment: What is the running time of this? I assume it O(n) where n = # of nodes?

Comment: @HenleyChiu it is linear - you run two BFS and each of them is linear with respect to the number of edges(which is in the order of number of nodes for a tree)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
public static TreeAttr calcTreeDiameter(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return new TreeAttr(0, 0);

    TreeAttr leftAttr = calcTreeDiameter(root.getLeft());
    TreeAttr rightAttr = calcTreeDiameter(root.getRight());

    int maxDepth = Math.max(leftAttr.depth, rightAttr.depth);
    int maxDiam = Math.max(leftAttr.diameter, rightAttr.diameter);
    maxDiam = Math.max(maxDiam, leftAttr.depth + rightAttr.depth + 1);

    return new TreeAttr(maxDiam, maxDepth + 1);
}
```

The TreeAttr is a simple structure containing the diameter and depth of a subtree. Both should be passed in the recursion, since the optimum may either come from one of the subtrees, or from the concatenation of the longest paths.

Comment: Now I see that my solution is equivalent to Mikhail Vladimirov's solution.

Comment: yeah...Its equivalent and Mikhail's one is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max=0;
public int diameter(Tree root) {
  if(root==null) return 0;
  int l=diameter(root.left);
  int r=diameter(root.right);
  max=Math.max(max,l+r+1);
  return l>r:l+1:r+1;
}
```

max is the max diameter.

Comment: This solution has problems. For example, it returns an incorrect result(2) for a root with two leaf children. Also, note that max variable isn't used.

Comment: @EyalSchneider the final result should return max as the max diameter not the returned value for this func

Comment: I see. So you actually have a depth function with a side effect stored in max. I would change the function name...

Answer (score 0):

Algo takes O(n). Calculates height and path at the same time.

```
public static int findLongestPath(TreeNode root)
{
  // longest path = max (h1 + h2 + 2, longestpath(left), longestpath(right);

  int[] treeInfo = longestPathHelper(root);

  return treeInfo[0];
}

private static int[] longestPathHelper(TreeNode root)
{
  int[] retVal = new int[2];

  if (root == null)
  {
     //height and longest path are 0
     retVal[0] = 0;
     retVal[1] = 0;
  }

  int[] leftInfo = longestPathHelper(root.getLeft());
  int[] rightInfo = longestPathHelper(root.getRight());

  retVal[0] = Math.max(leftInfo[1] + rightInfo[1] + 2, Math.max(leftInfo[0], rightInfo[0]));
  retVal[1] = Math.max(leftInfo[1], rightInfo[1]) + 1;

  return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the height of the tree to calculate the diameter. Make a getHeight() function which will take the root of the tree as argument and return the height of the tree. Using this value and with the help of recursion we can calculate the diameter of the tree. Here is the code for it.....

Function for calculating the diameter :-

```
public static int getDiameter(BinaryTreeNode root) {        
  if (root == null)
    return 0;

int rootDiameter = findHeight(root.getLeft()) + findHeight(root.getRight()) + 1;
int leftDiameter = getDiameter(root.getLeft());
int rightDiameter = getDiameter(root.getRight());

return Math.max(rootDiameter, Math.max(leftDiameter, rightDiameter));
}
```

Function for calculating the height of tree:-

```
public static int findHeight(BinaryTreeNode node) {
if(node == null)
    return 0;

else {
    return 1+Math.max(findHeight(node.left), findHeight(node.right));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Diameter of a Binary Tree in O(n), It will track the diameter passing through root node or not and uses the same height function to track the diameter.

**DiameterOfTree.class**

```
import BinaryTree.BinaryTreeNode;

public class DiameterOfBinaryTree {
    private int DIAMETER = 0;

    public void getDiameterOfBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode node) {
        getHeightUtil(node, DIAMETER);
        System.out.print("\n\n Maximum Diameter of the tree is : " + DIAMETER);
    }

    private int getHeightUtil(BinaryTreeNode node, Integer maXValue) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Here we get the maximum value returned + 1 for each subtree left or 
        //  right 
        int leftHeight = getHeightUtil(node.getLeft(), maXValue); 
        int rightHeight = getHeightUtil(node.getRight(), maXValue);

        //finding the new diameter at a particular node and adding 1 to 
        //include that particular node as well: leftHeight + rightHeight + 1 
        DIAMETER = Math.max(DIAMETER, leftHeight + rightHeight + 1);

        return 1 + Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package BinaryTree;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initialise root
        BinaryTreeNode root = new BinaryTreeNode(40);

        //Create a binary Tree
        InitialiseBinaryTree initialiseBinaryTree = new InitialiseBinaryTree();
        initialiseBinaryTree.initialise(root);

        // Find the diameter of the binary tree 
        new DiameterOfBinaryTree().getDiameterOfBinaryTree(root);
    }

}
```

**InitialiseBinaryTree.java**

```
package BinaryTree;

class InitialiseBinaryTree {
    void initialise(BinaryTreeNode root) {
        BinaryTreeOperation bto = new BinaryTreeOperation();
        int[] data = {20, 50, 10, 30, 5,8, 25, 32, 33};
        for (int aData : data) {
            bto.insertElementInBinaryTree(root, aData);
        }
    }
}
```

**BinaryTreeOperation.java**

```
package BinaryTree;

class BinaryTreeOperation {
    private boolean findInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode node, int data) {
        return node != null &&
                (data == node.getData() || (findInBinaryTree(node.getLeft(), data) || findInBinaryTree(node.getRight(), data)));
    }

    void insertElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode node, int data) {
        if (node == null) {
            new BinaryTreeNode(data);
        } else {
            insertHelper(node, data);
        }
    }

    private void insertHelper(BinaryTreeNode node, int data) {
        if (node.getData() > data) {
            if (node.getLeft() == null) {
                node.setLeft(new BinaryTreeNode(data));
            } else {
                insertHelper(node.getLeft(), data);
            }
        } else {
            if (node.getRight() == null) {
                node.setRight(new BinaryTreeNode(data));
            } else {
                insertHelper(node.getRight(), data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```