# Is anyone familiar with the "Diameter of a Binary Tree" question on Leetcode?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am having a hard time understanding the "Diameter of a Tree" question on leetcode, and though I was able to see the solution it's no use if I won't be able to come up with one on my own since I don't understand the question, to begin with. I ask if anyone could please explain step by step how this problem is approached, I would greatly appreciate it.
Here is the question:

Given a binary tree, you need to compute the length of the diameter of the tree. The diameter of a binary tree is the length of the longest path between any two nodes in a tree. This path may or may not pass through the root.

Example:
Given a binary tree

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \     
  4   5
```

Return 3, which is the length of the path [4,2,1,3] or [5,2,1,3].

Note: The length of path between two nodes is represented by the number of edges between them.

Here is the solution:

```
class Solution {
    int ans;
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        ans = 0;
        depth(root);
        return ans;
    }
    public int depth(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return 0;
        int L = depth(node.left);
        int R = depth(node.right);
        ans = Math.max(ans, L + R);
        return 1 + Math.max(L, R);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/ Or this: [Find the diameter of a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953979/find-the-diameter-of-a-binary-tree)

Answer (score 0):

The `diameter` asked represents the depth of your `Tree`.
This algorithm use a recursive method `depth` to compare each child node `node.left` and `node.right` and add 1 to count the node itself.
With your example :

- (A) 1/2/4 => return 3
- (B) 1/2/5 => return 3
- (C) 1/2/* => return 3 (as max of A & B is 3)
- (D) 1/3/* => return 2
- (E) 1/* => return 3 (as max of C & D is 3).

`depth` of `E` (your root node) is `3`.